# How to limit the available DateTime ranges in a Google form? Only Next 4 weeks may be available, and strictly between 17:30PM < 20:30PM date

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-forms, datebox

I would like to know: How to limit the available DateTime ranges in a Google form? Only Next 4 weeks may be available, and strictly between 17:30PM < 20:30PM date. 
Indeed, I am free to help a non-profit association 3 hours everyday, but I am now spending more time replying email for appointments.
I know there is a lot of tools to do that, but i prefer Google products.
I am very new in programming
Kind regards

Comment: not possible with google forms. at most you can automate a reply saying them o pick a different option.